# Check dynamically if values are mandatory and then check if the mandatory values are null

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, react-native, object

I have this object state which I have intialized it as initialSegement

I have created this component when I set the state of every field startDate, endDate etc and all is working fine there.

I want to create this function called validateSegement which will be boolean. If this function returns true, then the button to add a segment will be enabled.

I have created this function, but unfortunately is not dynamic.

The issue is that these fields are configured dynamically by the user if they're mandatory or not. So I want to find a way of doing this by first checking if fields are mandatory and second checking if the mandatory fields are empty or not.

I can find out if the fields are mandatory from a response from the backend, which for this case I will suppose the response is like this:

Comment: Keep in mind that the Object `ISegment` is still a Javascript object.   As such you should be able to loop through the properties of your server definitions and check to see if each field is truthy.   think about looping through your server definition keys, and seeing if segment[key] is truthy if `mandatory` is true

Comment: @Todd could you provide an example of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Segment = {
  id: string;
  startDate?: string;
  endDate?: string;
  startTime?: string;
  endTime?: string;
}

type MaybeOptionalField = keyof Omit<Segment, "id">

const configurations: Record<MaybeOptionalField, {mandatory: boolean, text: string}> = {
  startDate: {
    mandatory: true,
    text: "test"
  },
  endDate: {
    mandatory: false,
    text: "test"
  },
  startTime: {
    mandatory: false,
    text: "test"
  },
  endTime: {
    mandatory: false,
    text: "test"
  }
};

const segments: Segment[] = [{
    id: 'foo',
    startDate: "now",
}, {
    id: 'bar',
}]

// figure out which fields are currently required
const mandatoryFields = Object.entries(configurations)
    .filter(([_, configuration]) => configuration.mandatory)
    // Object.entries treats 'key' to always be type any string, but we'd like to maintain the keys as being of type MaybeOptionalField
    // which keeps `segment[mandatoryField]` as being valid, one could instead push the type assertion into the for loop below
    .map(([key]) => key as MaybeOptionalField)

const validateSegment = (segment: Segment) => {
  for (const mandatoryField of mandatoryFields) {
    if (!segment[mandatoryField]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
};

const validSegments = segments.filter(segment => validateSegment(segment))
const invalidSegments = segments.filter(segment => !validateSegment(segment))

console.log(validSegments, validSegments.length)
console.log(invalidSegments, invalidSegments.length)
```